# How to send a Request to HTTP server in multiline form through command line?

Tags: http, command-line, request, command, telnet

I wanna send Request to a HTML page through the command line (Telnet client) and I just can't do that.

I write:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

and then when I want to move to the next line to write the host name and press the "enter" key, it doesn't do that, it just executes that command and says: "Invailed command". I tried to set localecho and crlf and it didn't work.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Just to make it clear, I want to write it in it's actual form: GET /index.cfm?test=1 HTTP/1.1
host: www.myserver.com

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you just started telnet without any additional commandline options.
You have to start it using your requested server name and port number:

```
$ telnet some.page.com 80
```

and then it should work.

You can also specify server and port in telnet:

```
telnet> open google.com 80
```

Comment: Well, I did it, but I want to run the request manually. How can I do that?

Comment: And by manually I mean to the way it looks and it's structure:

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand what you mean by "manually".. everything I wrote I did "manually".. could you rephrase the question?

Comment: by manually I mean fully send the Request like the way it really sents to the browser, with the method, page name, server version, and host. Ex: 
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com

Comment: I'm puzzled.. what exactlty prevents you from doing it? To make myself clear - I mean: 1) run `telnet`, 2) write `open google.com 80`, 3) write your request: `GET / HTTP/1.1<Enter>Host: www.google.com<Enter><Enter>` - done. Does this work?

Comment: I can't to that because after I write the HTTP version (HTTP/1.1) and than press the return key to write the host name, it executes what I wrote and I can't write another line

Comment: And did you use `open <server> 80` before?